# Bash in vi mode: why do I sometimes have to press A, a, i or I twice to get to insert mode?

Tags: bash

When working in bash vi mode, I sometimes notice I have to press A, a, I or i twice to get into insert mode. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: broken keyboard ;)

Comment: It happens when you press `ESC` twice. I hate this behavior of bash/readline.

Comment: indeed - pressing ESC twice is the cause. Thanks for that

Answer (score 3):

As mrucci said, the problem is pressing Esc twice. However, since he only commented and did not create an answer, this question is still listed as “unanswered”. Therefore I shamelessly create an answer. ;)